# Find index position of characters in string

Tags: python

I am trawling through a storage area and the paths look a lot like this: 
storagearea/storage1/ABC/ABCDEF1/raw/2013/05/ABCFGM1

I wont always know what year is it. I need to find the starting index position of the year

Therefor I am looking for where I find the following in the file name (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 etc...)

I have set up a list as follows:

```
list_ = ['2010', '2011','2012','2013','2014', '2015', '2016']
```

and I can find if it is in the file name

```
if any(word in file for word in list_): 
    print 'Yahooo'
```

But how do I find the character index of the year in the absolute path?

Comment: you want to use `index` to find the ordinal position of an element: `list_.index('2010')`

Comment: @EdChum I don't think this is a dupe of that question (although it's probably a dupe of some other). The main point of the question seems to be that OP does not know which of the year-strings is contained in the filename.

Comment: Yes exactly tobias_k

Comment: "find the starting index position of 2010" is ambiguous. The index of `'2010'` in what, and in what way?

Comment: Edit the relevant information into the question; don't dump it into a comment.

Comment: @tobias_k yes I've reopened this

Comment: Still ambiguous. You want to know which year was found? Or you want to know the character index of `'2010'` in that absolute path? Or you want to know how many directories deep it is? Or what? Again, add it to the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a generator expression (which has its own scope), use a traditional loop and then print the found word's index and `break` when you find a match:

```
list_ = ['2010', '2011','2012','2013','2014', '2015', '2016']
for word in list_:
    if word in file:
        print file.index(word)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `join`ing those years to a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) using `'|'` as a delimiter...

```
>>> list_ = ['2010', '2011','2012','2013','2014', '2015', '2016']
>>> p = "|".join(list_)
>>> p
'2010|2011|2012|2013|2014|2015|2016'
```

... and then using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to find a match and `span()` and `group()` to find the position of that match and the matched year itself:

```
>>> filename = "storagearea/storage1/ABC/ABCDEF1/raw/2013/05/ABCFGM1"
>>> m = re.search(p, filename)
>>> m.group()
'2013'
>>> m.span()
(37, 41)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python string.index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index)

```
string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])¶

    Like find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
```